# svn:designate a file as not subject for source control

Tags: svn, macos

I have a project folder with sources, headers, resources, etc. Most files are subject to source control via SVN, but some are not. Is there a way to designate a file as not subject to source control, ever, so that "svn status" does not throw a line with a question mark next to that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, add it as a value of the `svn:ignore` property on the containing folder.

For example with this structure:

```
SomeDirectory
SomeDirectory\somefile.txt
```

you can run

```
svn propset svn:ignore somefile.txt SomeDirectory
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the svn propset svn:ignore command.

In addition, if you are using TortoiseSVN you can also right-click a file in the commit window when you are committing your changes and choose to ignore that file.